# Kubuntu 17.10x64 suddenly asks me to log out, then turns off the computer (with bonus mouse problems)

Tags: kubuntu, mouse, crash

So, some 3-4 weeks ago, my laptop suddenly shows me the log out screen, with the usual 30s timer running down on the bottom; since I didn't go to the menu / application launcher and this just came out of the blue, I clicked cancel. At this point, the screen goes back to whatever it was I was doing, but one second later (at most), the computer turns itself off (no shutdown procedure). When I press the power key, it comes back, successfully goes through POST (as far as I could tell, and as far as I remember), but freezes in a blank screen afterwards (no Kubuntu "splash" logo). Hard-cycling the power lets me back into the computer, no problems.

Last week, the same thing happened, with the slight difference that it didn't crash / freeze after POST. I scratched this off to computers being computers, and went about my business.

Just now, it happened a third time, with the post-POST freeze; again, pressing the power key for 4 seconds to power down the computer, and then bringing it back up "solved" the problem.

This time there may have been a small (?) difference. I can't quite remember, but it may be possible (likely, even) that in the first 2 occurrences the system had updates pending, waiting me for reboot, with the little "please reboot" notification in the system tray; I frequently ignore them, sometimes for days. However, this third time I am sure I had not such reminders.

To make matters odder, the 3 situations developed some sort of problems with my external mouse (the touchpad always worked). When the system got to the desktop, the mouse wouldn't move. When I moved the wireless dongle to another USB port, it would come back to life; when moving the dongle back to its designated port (the one in the back, out of the way), it wouldn't work again. However, at the next "crash", the mouse died again, and using any of the 2 previous ports wouldn't work (and at the 3rd "crash", the previous 3 ports were dead). The ports work just fine otherwise (with pendrives), just not with the mouse.

What gives? Thanks!

Comment: Wow, that is extremely odd. Can you post the `dmesg` output for the crash?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. The issue with your mouse isn't likely to be related  to the unscheduled logout and shutdown which are also likely due to seperate causes. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Sure. What options do I use dmesg with? Also, I'm looking at the log, and where do I start and how far back do I go? There are no timestamps on it. Tks